# Sending not only form input via a POST request but other data as well

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to "develop" an application that stores todo tasks in a table. These tasks are organised like sub tasks for a "head" task.

The problem is that when submitting an input as a sub task via POST I need the name of the head-task as well. I can't figure out how to send the information have stored in my `<h1>`-label with the information I have in my `<input>`.

Here is my code example:

```
<h1>Taskheader</h1>
<form action="/todo/task/" method="post">
     <input type="text" name="Taskitem">
     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Is it possible to send this information off, without using overly complicated code for a beginner?

Comment: why can't you add a hidden input with the header value?

Comment: When generating page, you can add input of type hidden in each form, if you have separate form per each head-task. Just like @walucas said. However if there is just one form on the page, you need some user interaction in selecting head-task and maybe JavaScript code to handle that.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. So there is no obvious way to implement this without a hidden input field or javaScript?

Answer (score 0):

give the `h1` an id for example `id = "header-task-name"` then get the `h1` element by that `id` and get the input text both using javascript, finally send the task header and the input text using post and ajax to the server.

another approach is to wrap each task header and it's form in a div then get the parent div of the form using this :

```
var x = document.getElementById("the form").parentElement.nodeName;
```

then you can access the header of the form by using the parent div to get the `h1` child